# My computer turned itself into Tablet Mode and it won't come out despite settings

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron, laptop-display, tablet-mode

I went to edit a photo in Windows 10 and didn't realize it had switched into Tablet Mode until I closed that and found the screen sideways. (I didn't even know there was a Tablet Mode, and didn't enable it.) This is a regular laptop, not one where the screen turns into a tablet. I googled and found the settings. I've turned Tablet Mode off, set it to start up on the Desktop, set it to ask me before switching, and to hide icons.

It will not come out of Tablet Mode in spite of these settings and restarting a few times. Help!!

Comment: Press the Action Center icon, bottom right of your screen, hit Table Mode which should be highlighted when enabled.

Comment: I have already turned it off. I was set to Off when I went into that setting. I mentioned the settings in my question. Tablet Mode is set off yet it is in Tablet Mode.

Comment: Are you sure you're in Tablet mode and not just dealing with a rotated display & perhaps the Start menu set to Full Screen? Some of the popular graohics adapters have hotkey combinations to rotate the display.

Answer (score 1):

I had a laptop get confused in the same way a couple of weeks ago.
(Also after editing a photo.)

I had to ENABLE tablet mode in Action center first.
Then did a full shutdown.
Started back up and now Windows was again in Tablet mode and the indicator in the Action Center showed correct state.
Then I could switch off the Tablet mode via Action Center.

Still don't know how it got in Tablet mode in the first place. I have not been able to reproduce the effect either.

Answer (score 0):

1. open action center using `windows+a` or click it from the taskbar beside the clock in the right bottom corner (if you are using right-to-right language it will be on the left bottom corner)
2. click expand if it's not expanded
3. click on tablet mode to turn it off

Comment: I have already turned it off. I was set to Off when I went into that setting. I mentioned the settings in my question. Tablet Mode is set off yet it is in Tablet Mode.

Comment: so nothing happens when you turn it on and off ?